# Order() in R - argument is missing, with no default

Tags: r

Here is the gist of my problem.
I inner joined two dataframes. Called it MergedData.
I wanted to group the data by customer and sales.
This gives me what I want -

```
data2 <- aggregate(MergedData$Purchase~ MergedData$User_ID+ 
                          MergedData$Product_Category,data = MergedData, FUN =  sum)

 MergedData$User_ID MergedData$Product_Category MergedData$Purchase
1            1000002                           1                3267
2            1000003                           1                 768
3            1000005                           1                4063
```

Now I want to sort it by MergedData$Purchase. So, I try this -

```
data2 <- data2[order(data2$`MergedData$User_ID`,
                -data2$`MergedData$Purchase`)]
```

It returns me the following error -

```
**Error in `[.data.frame`(data2, order(data2$`MergedData$User_ID`, -data2$`MergedData$Purchase`)) : 
  undefined columns selected**
```

If I put a comma after `-data2$`MergedData$Purchase, it returns me another error-

```
**Error in order(data2$`MergedData$User_ID`, -data2$`MergedData$Purchase`,  : 
  argument is missing, with no default**
```

I am a total newbie to R.
Can someone please help me troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only used one index to `data2`, so the result of `order` is being treated as column names.  Write it with a comma after `order(...)`, and the order will be on the rows for all columns:

```
data2 <- data2[order(data2$`MergedData$User_ID`,
            -data2$`MergedData$Purchase`), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

no need for `MergedData`, in your `order` statement.

```
data2 <- data2[order(data2$`MergedData$User_ID`,
                -data2$`MergedData$Purchase`)]
```

should be

```
data2 <- data2[order(data2$User_ID,
                -data2$Purchase)]
```